# Javascript post запрос

Tags: ajax, javascript

Выполняю такой скрипт

```
function call() {
  var text_1 = $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'check.php',
      data: text_1,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.xxx').html(data);
      },
    });
    setTimeout(check, 500);
}
```

Вопрос - как мне получить данные на другом конце?

Comment: @TheGunth, уточните, что у вас "на другом конце". PHP, Java, Python, Node.js, Ruby, ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: Прошу прощения, только что нашел решение проблемы:
На другом конце у меня php, как оказалось нужно было снимать post запрос как и обычно - будто я и не использую js.
P.S.Это для тех у кого возможно будет такая проблема.

Comment: @TheGunth просто для себя поймите, что ajax - это тот же самый запрос, только страничка в браузере не перезагружается))

Answer (score 2):

POST-запрос обычно делается таким образом:

```
$.post("check.php", {name_1:value_1, name_2:value_2}, function(data){
    ...код, выполняемый после запроса...
});
```

Можно передавать массивы:

```
$.post("check.php", {'array_1[]':[value_1, value_2], name_1:vale_3}, function(data){
    ...код, выполняемый после запроса...
});
```

А на том конце запроса (в PHP) ловите как обычные данные из формы - реквестом.

По крайней мере у меня так работает.

[мануал 1](http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.post/#urldatacallbacktype), [мануал 2](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_POST)